# Data in SQLflite database is not deleting, in my Flutter project

Tags: flutter, sqlite, backend, crud

So I have an issue of data not being deleted from my database. It is supposed to happen when a dismissible widget is swiped away.
This is the model class:

```
class DateModel {
  //define schema
  int? id;
  final String dateText;

  DateModel({this.id, required this.dateText});

  //convert json data to DateModel instance
  factory DateModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DateModel(id: json["id"], dateText: json["dateText"]);
  }

  //convert DateModel instance to json 
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {"id": id, "dateText": dateText};
}
```

Below is where some CRUD operations are defined. I concluded that the error is because I'm not properly storing the id upon insert (in the "add" function). Although I'm not certain I'm doing this right.

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static Database? _db;

  //create singleton
  DatabaseHelper._constructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._constructor();

  Future<Database> get db async {
    return _db ??= await init_db("Date.db");
  }

  //create database when it doesn't exist
  Future<Database> init_db(String name) async {
    //locate database
    var databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasePath, name);

    //open database and return
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  //Create date table
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db
        .execute("CREATE TABLE Dates (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dateText TEXT)");
  }

  //add user input to table
  Future<int> add(DateModel dateModel) async {
    Database db = await instance.db;

    //store id of inserted date (generated by db.insert method)
    final id = await db.insert("Dates", dateModel.toMap());
    return dateModel.id = id;
  }

  //remove date from table
  Future<int> remove(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.db;
    return await db.delete("Dates", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<List> getDates() async {
    Database db = await instance.db;
    final data = await db.rawQuery("SELECT dateText FROM Dates");
    if (data.isNotEmpty) {
      return data;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

And lastly, this is where the delete action is supposed to take place (in dismissible's onDismissed property):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Date>(builder: (context, date, child) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getDates(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SlideTransition(
                    position:
                        Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
                            .animate(CurvedAnimation(
                                parent: _controller, curve: Curves.bounceIn)),
                    child: Dismissible(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
                        onDismissed: (direction) async {
                          final dateModel =
                              DateModel(dateText: date.dateList[index]);

                          //remove from list
                          date.dateList.removeAt(index);

                        //remove from database
                         await DatabaseHelper.instance.remove(dateModel.id!);
                        },
                        child: ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data![index].toString()))),
                  );
                });
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

I get the error that I'm doing a null check on a null value, which I believe is the dateModel.id.

I tried storing the id upon insert a couple of different ways. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to do exactly that: Putting a null check operator on a null value.

You are creating the dateModel like this:

```
final dateModel = DateModel(dateText: date.dateList[index]);
```

You do not pass any value for the `id`, which then is null.

Try something like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> dateJson = snapshot.data![index] as Map<String, dynamic>;
DateModel dateModel = DateModel.fromMap(dateJson);
date.dateList.removeAt(index);
await DatabaseHelper.instance.remove(dateModel.id);
```

PS: You should not make the id optional in your DateModel class since this should always be given.

Comment: Thak you, adding this to my onDismissed. Should I also apply this logic for when I add to the database?

Comment: When adding to the database and you also want to automatically add the data to the list when the upload was successful, you should indeed do this. Keep in mind that in this case maybe a StreamBuilder instead of a FutureBuilder would make more sense since it would automatically add or remove your data.